# ¿Cómo funciona indexOf de JavaScript en este caso?

Tags: javascript

Al registrar un correo necesito saber si no se encuentra en un **array** de datos **spam** los cuales no pueden ser utilizados para registrar un correo, Mi duda es cómo funciona exactamente la función `indexOf`: envío como correo *NOTENGO@yahoo.com* y si hace el match, ¿cómo es que compara solo la parte izquierda del @, aún no teniendo el dominio agregado en el arreglo?

```
this.checkEmail("NOTENGO@yahoo.com");

checkEmail(email: string) {
    let emails = [
      "@outlook.co",
      "@otlook.es",
      "@hahoo.com",
      "@YAOO.COM.MX",
      "@yahoo.com.mex",
      "NODIOCORREO",
      "NOMBRE",
      "NOTENGO",
      "NOVALIDO",
      "PACHO"
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
      if (email.indexOf(emails[i]) !== -1) console.log("encontrado");
    }
```

El ejemplo de arriba devuelve *encontrado* aunque solo haga match la palabra *NOTENGO* y no el correo completo *NOTENGO@yahoo.com*.

Comment: El código en su forma actual no corre correctamente :)

Comment: Si alguna respuesta resuelve tu problema no olvides marcarla como respuesta...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función indexOf busca una sub-cadena dentro de una cadena y Retorna El comienzo de la sub-cadena encontrada, si no encuentra la sub-cadena retornará -1. Lo que significa que tu al mandarle "nombre" al indexOf como sub-cadena el buscará "nombre" en tu cadena y retorna el indice de donde encontró la "n" en la cadena.

```js
function indexOf(str,sub_str){
    let init=-1;//Nos indicará si ha encontrado la sub-cadena y donde la ha encontrado.
    let i=0;//índice de la sub-cadena
    if (str.length<sub_str.length)return false;//La sub-cadena no puede tener más caracteres que la cadena.
    for (let c=0;c<msg["str_2"].length && i<sub_str.length;c++){
        if (init!=-1){//Ya encontró el inicio
            if (str[c]!=sub_str[i++])
                return -1;//Si hay un carácter de la sub-cadena que no concuerde con la parte de la cadena entonces
        }else{//Todavía no se ha encontrado el índice.
            if (str[c]==sub_str[i++]){
                init=c;
            }
        }
    }
    return init;
}
let msg={
    "str_1":"Hola mundo",
    "str_2":[
        "Batata",
        'H',
        "Holas",
        "Hola",
        "Hola mundos",
        "Hola mundo"
    ]
};
for (let str of msg["str_2"]){
    console.log("¿"+msg["str_1"]+" comienza con "+str+"?: "+indexOf(msg["str_1"],str));
}
```

Mi consejo es que llenes los arrays con los nombres de usuarios y su tipo de correo electrónicos y también que crees otro array para verificar si es correcto el nombre de dominio:

```js
let users=["daniel@gmail.com","tucodigo@outlook.com",...];
const correos_validos=["gmail.com","outlook.com","hotmail.com","yahoo.com"];//Solo conosco estos.
```

Y al hacer el la verificación solo debes hacer como te dijeron en otra respuesta un split la signo @ y verifica que la segunda parte coincida con los correos válidos.

```js
let users=["daniel@gmail.com","tucodigo@outlook.com","otrocorreo@noexiste.com"];
const correos_validos=["gmail.com","outlook.com","hotmail.com","yahoo.com"];//Solo conosco estos.
function checkEmail(email){
    let gmail=email.split("@")[1];
    if (users.indexOf(email)!=-1){//Si conseguimos el correo electrónico:
        if (correos_validos.indexOf(gmail)==-1){
            console.error("Error, se guardó un correo electronico invalido, acomoden ese sistema diganle a mi flojo desarrollador que me acomode ahora o será despedido;(.\nusuario: "+email+"\ncorreo: "+gmail);
            return true;//Porque si lo encontró:)-
        }
        return true;//O si quieres pones un mensaje de encontrado.
    }
}
let correos_for_tester=[
    "m@gmail.com",
    "daniel@gmail.com",
    "otrocorreo@noexiste.com",
    "Estenoseencontrara@outlook.com"
];
correos_for_tester.forEach((x)=>{
    if (checkEmail(x))
        console.log("El correo '"+x+"' se encontró");
    else
        console.log("El correo '"+x+"' no se encontró");
})
```

Comment: creo que es typescript de algun framework; angular, react o vue... por eso usa esa forma de escribir el codigo... pero en si el indexOf es de javascript nativo.

Comment: Interesante, gracias por el dato. Me quedo con JS nativo :) @ArcanisGK507

Comment: yo tambien ... no le veo sentido a implementar un framework del framework del framework ...

Answer (score 3):

Lo tienes al revés.
El método `indexOf` debe recorrer el array, no la cadena a buscar.
Además, no hace falta hacer un for para recorrer el array, eso ya lo hace el indexOf

Cámbialo por esto:

```
var indice=emails.indexOf(email)
if (indice!== -1) console.log(emails[indice] + " encontrado");
```

`.indexOf` devuelve el índice donde se encuentra `email` dentro del array `emails`. Y si no lo encuentra, devuelve -1

Comment: Hola Enrique si funciona, en este enlace lo puedes comprobar  https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-fermat-65lycu?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:291-328

Comment: Te he editado la respuesta, no me había dado cuenta que estabas haciendo un for innecesario.

Comment: @EnriqueGarcia el no quiere que encuentre un correo completo; solo quire que encuentr el correo sin el dominio hay la cosa cambia por que tienes que hacerle un split a cada correo para evaluar la parte del nombre del correo y no el dominio.

Comment: Creo que simplemente preguntaba por qué no funcionaba bien el indexOf y no se explicaba por qué solicitando "NOTENGO@yahoo.com" la función le devolvía como bueno "NOTENGO". Es lo que sigo entiendo en su pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que intentas hacer esta bien pero antes de validar el indexof tienes que partir el correo si solo quieres evaluar la parte del nombre del correo y no el dominio del correo quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
this.checkEmail("NOTENGO@yahoo.com");

checkEmail(email: string) {
    let emails = [
      "@outlook.co",
      "@otlook.es",
      "@hahoo.com",
      "@YAOO.COM.MX",
      "@yahoo.com.mex",
      "NODIOCORREO",
      "NOMBRE",
      "NOTENGO",
      "NOVALIDO",
      "PACHO"
    ];

    let mailArr = email.split("@");

    let indice=emails.indexOf(mailArr[0])
    if (indice!== -1) console.log(emails[indice] + " encontrado");
}
```

el problema como se indica es que esto no evalua la parte del dominio y por lo que veo en tu ejemplo tienes dominios; si quieres evaluar tambien los dominios tendrias que usar dos indices:

```
this.checkEmail("NOTENGO@yahoo.com");

checkEmail(email: string) {
    let emails = [
      "@outlook.co",
      "@otlook.es",
      "@hahoo.com",
      "@YAOO.COM.MX",
      "@yahoo.com.mex",
      "NODIOCORREO",
      "NOMBRE",
      "NOTENGO",
      "NOVALIDO",
      "PACHO"
    ];

    let mailArr = email.split("@");

    let indice1=emails.indexOf(mailArr[0]);
    let indice2=emails.indexOf(mailArr[1]);
    if (indice1!== -1 || indice2!== -1) console.log(email + " encontrado");
}
```

[Documentacion split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Si quieres evaluar no solo que sea igual si no que quieres evaluar si el correo contiene un sub-string entonces puedes hechar manos a [includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)

---

Nueva Pregunta del OP en los comentarios: **Qunque no este el dominio devuelve encontrado mi pregunta es porque?***

Respuesta: en los ejemplos que doy estoy usando el array que compartiste; el cual contiene dominios o nombres de correo, y no un correo exacto. cuando se pasa un correo simplemente se valida 1 o las dos partes del correo de manera individual y no un correo exacto; para evaluar un string es un correo valido y que no esta en la lista; tu lista debe contener tambien el correo exacto que buscas bloquear y el string debe contener el parttern regex como se demuestra en esta otra pregunta/respuesta del sitio en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/17161735 pero en tu post nunca has preguntado como validar que un string es un correo o tiene el formato de correo.

Comment: mm creo que me di a entender mal, ingresando el correo NOTENGO@live.com aunque no este el dominio devuelve encontrado mi pregunta es porque ?

Comment: Se verifica el dominio porque es capaz que el usuario no tiene outlook.com o no esta registrado con ese correo y tu pones que si esta registrado con ese dominio(Lo que puede causar errores)

Comment: @GerardoBautista que quieres decir con: *aunque no esté el dominio* puedes ser más detallado de que esperas que ocurra???

Comment: tu quieres validar que el string es un correo???